# DataContractSerializer can't find reference?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

at first: sorry if this is a long and code heavy question. i am trying to serialize and deserialize a class called level that looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Level
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Face> faces;

    public Level()
    {
        Face a = new Face();
        Face b = new Face();
        Face c = new Face();
        Face d = new Face();

        a.edges.Add(new Edge(b, c));
        b.edges.Add(new Edge(a, c));
        c.edges.Add(new Edge(a, d));
        d.edges.Add(new Edge(a, b));

        this.faces = new List<Face>() { a, b, c, d };
    }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Face
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Edge> edges;
    public Face()
    {
        this.edges = new List<Edge>();
    }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Edge
{
    [DataMember]
    public Face a;
    [DataMember]
    public Face b;

    public Edge(Face a, Face b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

since there are circular references i need to enable the reference function of the datacontract serializer.However when i run this i get the error

> SerializationException: Deserialized object with reference Id 'i1' was not found

the serialize and deserialize functions look like this:

```
// object to be serialized
public Level level;

public void Serialize()
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Level));
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "test.xml"), FileMode.Create);
    Debug.Log("serial");
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, level);
    stream.Close();
}

// function to serialize an object to a json text file
public void Deserialize()
{
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "test.xml"), FileMode.Open);
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Level));

    Level loaded = (Level)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

    stream.Close();
}

void Start()
{
    level = new Level();
    Serialize();

    Deserialize();
}
```

here is also a serialized xml example:

```
<Level xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
    <faces>
        <Face z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
            <edges>
                <Edge z:Id="i2">
                    <a z:Id="i3">
                        <edges>
                            <Edge z:Id="i4">
                                <a z:Ref="i1" />
                                <b z:Id="i5">
                                    <edges>
                                        <Edge z:Id="i6">
                                            <a z:Ref="i1" />
                                            <b z:Id="i7">
                                                <edges>
                                                    <Edge z:Id="i8">
                                                        <a z:Ref="i1" />
                                                        <b z:Ref="i3" />
                                                    </Edge>
                                                </edges>
                                            </b>
                                        </Edge>
                                    </edges>
                                </b>
                            </Edge>
                        </edges>
                    </a>
                    <b z:Ref="i5" />
                </Edge>
            </edges>
        </Face>
        <Face z:Ref="i3" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
        <Face z:Ref="i5" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
        <Face z:Ref="i7" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
    </faces>
</Level>
```

i searched for an answer for a few days now and still didn't get any close.
Can you give me a hint on how to solve this please?

Comment: code here looks entirely relevant and appropriate - don't apologise!

Comment: I tried with your code, and it worked fine; taking a look at the xml example

Comment: when I run `Deserialize()` with your example xml: it works fine. What platform are you targeting?

Comment: i am running this in the game engine unity. The problem might be with unity if it's working for you. If so i'm glad that you tested this and exclude the code as the source of the error.

Comment: if you're targeting unity, DCS could work a little different... sadly I don't "unity" so it is kinda hard for me to test it there, sorry

Comment: ok thanks a lot. I will do some more research in serialization with unity. can i somehow award you for your afford?

Comment: not really... "works on my machine" doesn't count for much.

Comment: Can you please post the full exception stack? Where does it break? When you serialize or when you deserialize? I am betting it's the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem may be that you are trying to deserialize something that you previously serialized **before** you added the `IsReference=true` parameter to the attribute.

If you delete your test file and create a new one with your updated code, the deserialization process should work without issue.